# GA how to define a segment to select users who were active for no longer then 3 days

Tags: google-analytics

I need to analyze activity of users who:

- had their first session between `start-date` and `end-date` from the request
- were active for no longer then 3 days after first session

Alternatively, a way to select users who :

- had their first session between `start-date` and `end-date` from the request
- had exactly 3 sessions

How should I define a segment to select those users?